# Bean Shell Script Returning 0 for latency in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using BeanShell Sampler to make a TCP connection/request as part of the load test. The problem now is that the results reported by jmeter always have latency as 0. I am not sure why this is the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't know what does your code do therefore it's not smart enough (yet?) to automatically calculate the latency for you so it's up to **you** to figure out the latency and report it via [SampleResult.setLatency() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setLatency-long-) somewhere in your code like:

```
SampleResult.setLatency(1234L);
```

Also [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting [as Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

And last but not the least, if your code only makes a TCP request you can use [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) or [HTTP Raw Request Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/), it will be faster and consume less resources

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I get the latency now...but I was wondering why Elapsed was actually being filled, but I have to manually get the latency myself. Got any ideas why this is the case?